# ASP.NET MVC application with not loading JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have app in the works that is an MVC app with many JavaScript files.  It is hosted on IIS as a standard web page. The necessary apps, like Web Platform and .NET Frameworks, are installed already on this server.

The hosted app is only loading a picture, however, I was expecting a login menu to be loaded via JavaScript.  The browser can't access the .js files in the sub-directory (404 error).

Nothing was changed in this app from when we deployed (manually) other than adding IUSR and IIS_IUSRS to access folders with write permissions. All folders and files are accessible by these users in this app's folder. But the browser cannot load anything other than the main web page with its picture.

There should be login menu visible that is made by .js scripts.  Does anyone have any idea what might cause that to happen?

Comment: Did you check the source of the page from your browser? Try opening the browser developer tools and inspecting the script tags to see how the src is defined, perhaps it's not mapped correctly? Look at the network tab and see where it is trying to find the resource.

Comment: There were missing .js files. Deployment didn't copied these files, they were set to other than Content, Copy always.

Comment: So were you able to fix it, or is it still a problem? If you fixed it, I'd recommend submitting an answer to your own question explaining what you did to fix it. If not, then perhaps update your question with more information, explain what you've tried and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was problem with some .js files as of build and deployment. There were files that have been not selected as "Content" in the build process.

Answer (score -1):

Since the description is not very clear, I can only provide some thoughts for trouble shooting:

1. Can you try different browsers? Your browser may have disable JS
   setting on.
2. Your server firework may not allow the JS files to be accessed.
3. Can you check your .csproj file? See if you have your JS file path
   included.
4. The read permission may not be inherited by the sub directories.